# Prevent Spring from creating new session if authentication fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

With the folowing code a new `WebSession` is created each time someone accesses my site. The state of the `WebSession` is set to `NEW` containing no attributes. This session is never deleted for some reason.

```
  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChainCatchAll(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/", "/static/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyExchange()
        .denyAll()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(this::returnPage)
        .accessDeniedHandler(this::returnPage)
        .and()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .build();
  }

  private Mono<Void> returnPage(ServerWebExchange exchange, RuntimeException denied) {
    Resource indexHtml = new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
    return ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).syncBody(indexHtml).flatMap(d -> d.writeTo(exchange, new HandlerStrategiesResponseContext(HandlerStrategies.withDefaults())));
  }

class HandlerStrategiesResponseContext implements ServerResponse.Context
{
  private final HandlerStrategies strategies;

  HandlerStrategiesResponseContext(HandlerStrategies strategies) {
    this.strategies = strategies;
  }

  @Override
  public List<HttpMessageWriter<?>> messageWriters() {
    return this.strategies.messageWriters();
  }

  @Override
  public List<ViewResolver> viewResolvers() {
    return this.strategies.viewResolvers();
  }
}
```

This is a catchall `ServerHttpSecurity` I have more specific configuration for my `/api` endpoint but they are working as expected when the `WebSession` is set in `STARTED` state and the attribute of `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`.

I have two questions regarding this.

1. What does it mean for `WebSession` to be in NEW state and why is that
   not deleted, only `STARTED` state is deleted.
2. What do I need to change to either not creating any session or make sure the sessions created are deleted when expired.